# Excel - lookup by multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Based on the attached screenshot, I have a sample database on the right side.
I would like to input random models, capacity, and grade on the right side, and receive an output of pricing.
How would I go about doing that? I think it has to be a mix of vlookup, index, and match?
Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure what's the purpose of Column X in your database, but I suggest you create a concatenated value from Model & Capacity in column X so that Lookup can be a bit easier.

See the below screenshot.

[image]

With reference to the sample data shown therein, the formula in E5

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B5&C5,$I$5:$M$10,MATCH(D5,{"A","B","C","D"},0)+1,FALSE),"Not Found")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. This formula shall now be enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's an array formula. Solution will not work if you do not create an Array Formula.

Drag it down along the required cells down.

Comment: Patkim, 

Thank you VERY much!
That worked like a charm.
I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MichaelRaduVasile if this answer has solved your issue, please check the box to mark it as accepted, so the question can be removed from the "unanswered" queue. Welcome to SuperUser!